# Headless testing in custom Docker image using Cypress/WebDriverIO

Tags: javascript, docker, testing, webdriver, headless

I am looking for a way to run either Cypress or WebDriverIO in a custom docker image. I do my development solely using docker (no volumes, no local files).

Is there a way to have either of the 2 libraries run in a custom docker image with headless browser? Would I need another image solely for Chrome, like selenium-standalone (which would be fine).

The goal would be = my node docker image with a TS app running -> either the testing infra included in that image with Chrome etc, or connection to another image that has Chrome running.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you take a look at this example project - https://github.com/blueimp/wdio ? It has the setup you are looking for.

Comment: @madhan that still looks like you still have to have the files locally, which I don't have, I have them cloned in docker.